# ASP.NET MVC: Can't get string parameter in my controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I have the following code in my controller called `UserController`:

```
public ActionResult Details(string name)
{
    MyModelDataContext db = new MyModelDataContext();
    Product user = db.Products.Single(t => t.Name == name);
    return View(user);
}
```

I expect that when I browse directly to `http://localhost:port/User/Details/SomeName`, I will reach this function with the "`name`" parameter containing "SomeName". I do get to this function, but "`name`" is null. I didn't change any of the default settings of the project.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Post please your route definitions from Global.asax.

Comment: @New in town: I did not change it, it's the default

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you haven't changed your route definitions in Global.asax.cs then I suppose it still uses the default "id" name for the parameter. Either change it there to "name" or rename your action parameter to "id".

Comment: +1 I changed the parameter name to "id" and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Have you defined a route in your global.asax that includes the 'name' parameter?

```
routes.MapRoute(  
"Default",                                       // Route name  
"{controller}/{action}/{name}",                    // URL w/ params  
new { controller="Home", action="Index",name="" }  // Param defaults  
);
```

See the example in the NerdDinner tutorial: http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part4.htm